# How to create second desktop entry for preview and stable android studio on Ubuntu

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I want to install android studio preview alongside the stable version.

> Download the .zip into ~/Download
>
> /home/zelongg/Downloads/android-studio-ide-171.4444016-linux-3.1-canary-4.zip
>
> sudo unzip android-studio-ide-171.4444016-linux-3.1-canary-4.zip -d
>   /usr/local/lib/android-studio-preview
>
> sudo mv -v /usr/local/lib/android-studio-preview/android-studio/*
>   /usr/local/lib/android-studio-preview/
>
> sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/android-studio-preview/android-studio/
>
> zelongg@zelongg:/usr/local/lib/android-studio-preview/bin$ ./studio.sh
>
> create a new folder in ~/Android/sdk in case that the newly downloaded
>   sdk will affect the sdk in mini project.

we can successfully run android studio preview 3.1 canary 4

But we cannot create the second desktop entry somehow.

https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/install-preview.html

The 2 desktop entry means:

What I want is that it should show 2 icons for both Android Studio and Android Studio Preview seperately. But now they share one icon in the left bar.

I followed the instructions below, but it doesn't work.

To make the preview version available in your list of applications, select Tools

> Create Desktop Entry from the Android Studio menu bar.

Comment: What is "2 desktop entry"?

Comment: @Alex.S it will show 2 icons for both android studio and android studio preview. Because now they share one icon in the left bar.

To make the preview version available in your list of applications, select Tools > Create Desktop Entry from the Android Studio menu bar.

Comment: I think the question is, why do you need to have both versions at all

Comment: @cricket_007 Because the official website shows that I can use stable and preview at the same time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I used `Create Desktop Entry` from Android Studio Preview, which replaced the `~/.local/share/applications/jetbrains-studio.desktop` of my stable version.

Then I copied that file to `~/.local/share/applications/jetbrains-studio-preview.desktop`.

The icon was still green, so I downloaded a yellow one and used it in the `.desktop` file:

[image: Android Studio Preview icon]

I also edited the `.desktop` file to suffix the name property with `Preview`

Then I ran the stable version to `Create Desktop Entry` to restore it.

Unity launcher didn't refresh the preview version icon and name straight away (it's ok after a reboot) and I couldn't figure out which one was which after typing `Android Studio` in the launcher. So I ran the `jetbrains-studio-preview.desktop` from its directory (first setting it to be executable), and then I locked it to the launcher. The result:

[image: Unity launcher running Android Studio stable along preview]

Comment: I followed these steps and it works! However when I open Preview, the icon of Stable is the one that gets highlighted. Did you come across this problem as well? Thanks.

Comment: I only encountered the problem, where restarting the Preview (like after update or from the menu) resulted in Stable getting an indicator instead. Closing Studio and starting Preview from the launcher was needed to get the indicator on Preview icon.

Comment: After duplicating the `.desktop` file as described, you can edit it and fix the paths. That would avoid the need for downloading the icon, which already exists inside of the install folder.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the accepted answer but had little difficulty since I am not so good with the terminal. so I installed *nautilus Admin. using the command `sudo apt-get install nautilus-admin`

open `Computer-> usr -> share` right click applications `select Open as Administrator`. (for this option u need to install nautilus admin as stated above). right click existing android studio desktop entry `select edit as Administrator`.

In that file change the `StartupWMClass` property to `jetbrains-studio-preview`. that is done. now open your newly installed android studio and create desktop entry. and .... that's it.

Comment: Thanks, but seems not works for `AndroidStudioPreview2022.1`

Comment: well, it was 3 years ago, i don't do android anymore, as far as I remember, in later versions, there was an option in the android studio startup screen to add this shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

just install stable and canary versions from ubuntu software store and their shortcuts are separate by default

Comment: All of peoples not using a weak distro, and may not install it via GUI store